# Could not locate email template for configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9

I am looking for the email template that renders configurable products HTML in transactional email. I have looked into email template folder and found this template `base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml` is rendering simple products html.
I have looked each and every file in email template folder but could not find how configurable products html are rendered in transactional emails.
Any one could tell me where I should try to locate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`default.phtml` file is responsible for rendering configurable product content in email template.

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```